# BOOTSTRAP 4 работает криво

Tags: html5, bootstrap4

Столкнулся с проблемой
При изучении bootstrap 4, надо было сделать вертикальное выравнивание сетки
Вот пример кода:

```
<div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
</div>
```

Но у меня почему-то ничего не работает, и колонки остаются на своих местах.
И так еще с несколькими заданиями было. Но, стили работают, отличие видно. Можете подсказать решение проблемы?

Comment: попробуйте обернуть все это дело в `container` или `container-fluid`

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло

Comment: Помогите кто-нибудь

Comment: О божечки)) Куда они выравнятся? Высоты то у row нет! Пример ниже.

Comment: Спасибо, правда уже сам ответ нашел )

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{border:2px solid #000}
.row{border:2px solid blue;height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
    <div class="col">Верх</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
    <div class="col">Середина</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
    <div class="col">Низ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```